# Searching for data after a string heading in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, strpos

I am trying to get the scripts to search the $open_email_msg which different e-mails will have different info but the same format as below. I just want whatever they put after Title: or Tags: or Categories: whatever that data is to be captured and not the string "Title:" or "Tags:" or "Categories:" This is just a snippet of the whole code, the rest inserts the info into a MySQL table and then is posted to a News Article on the site.

Can somebody help me find a solution to this please?

Strict e-mail message format:

> News Update
>   Title: Article Title
>   Tags: tag1 tag2
>   
> Categories: Article Category, 2nd Article Category
>   
> Snippet: Article snippet.
>   Message: 
>   Article Message. Images. More text, more text. Lorem impsum dolor sit amet.

```
<?php
//These functions searches the open e-mail for the the prefix defining strings.
    //Need a function to search after the space after the strings because the subject, categories, snippet, tags and message are constant-changing.
$subject = strpos($open_email_msg, "Title:");       //Searches the open e-mail for the string "Title" 
$categories = strpos($open_email_msg, "Categories:");       //Searches the open e-mail for the string "Categories"
$snippet = strpos($open_email_msg,"Snippet");           //Searches the open e-mail for the string "Snippet"
$content = strpos($open_email_msg, "Message");  //Searches the open-email for the string "Message"
$tags = str_replace(' ',',',$subject); //DDIE
$uri =  str_replace(' ','-',$subject); //DDIE
$when = strtotime("now");   //date article was posted

?>
```

Comment: If it's a strict format, can't you just split on newlines and go from there?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
preg_match_all('/([^:\\s]+): (.+)/', $open_email_msg, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

echo '<pre>' . print_r($matches, 1) . '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$lines = explode("\r\n", $open_email_msg); // Replace with whatever the line separator is
foreach($lines as $line){
    $temp = explode(": ", $line, 2);
    $msg[$temp[0]] = $temp[1];
}
// Now we have an array like
array(
    "Title" => "Article Title",
    "Tags" => "tag1 tag2",
    "Categories" => "Article Category, 2nd Article Category",
    "Snippet" => "Article Snippet",
    "Message" => "..."
)
```

Comment: what do you mean by line separator?

Comment: I used this and all it gave me was the word Array constantly where the date was supposed to be. why is that?